# Downloading Google Documents using api

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

this is shareable link [link to file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wzCjl51u131v1KBgpbiKLJs8DPPakhXCFosfYjp7BY0/edit?usp=sharing)

id = 1wzCjl51u131v1KBgpbiKLJs8DPPakhXCFosfYjp7BY0

so [manage downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) documentation.

```
file_id = '11wzCjl51u131v1KBgpbiKLJs8DPPakhXCFosfYjp7BY0'
request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                             mimeType='application/pdf')
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

i saved the file as dd.py, run using f5 and got this error

> line 2, in 
>       request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
>   NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

First off you cant be sure that the id you find in the shareable link is in fact the id of the file on google drive this is not always the case.  Actually I have never known this to be the case

> drive_service' is not defined

Second you need create the drive service and be authenticated before you can run that code. You should try following the [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Authentication successful. from quickstart.py  but                                   File "dd.py", line 2, in <module>
    request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined

Comment: if you check the code its called service in the tutorial.  you will need to rename your drive_service?

Comment: line 2, in <module>
    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
NameError: name 'service' is not defined

Comment: @greenseek seems like you have some issues with code that you don't present in your question. Consider asking a better question and/or reviewing variable scopes in Python.